# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command is not found

Tags: discord, discord.py

I finished a bot after a couple of hours and while trying to run it I get this error message 'discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found' I don't know why/ how to fix this could anyone help?
The chunk of code with the error will be below this text:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client
```

I tried running the bot multiple times and I've looked around overflow for an answer and found nothing :/

Comment: This seems to be in a cog. Is the cog actually loaded?

Comment: Uhm I don't think so where would I load the cog? Ik im dumb but I'm new to discord.py and just py all togeather srry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Comments mentioned you didn't load your cogs)

`discord.py` can't just "know" that it has to load your cogs, you have to do this yourself. This works through the process of `extensions`.

Extensions are loaded using `load_extension`. The best place to do this is `setup_hook` (don't use something like `on_ready`!). An extension is a file with a `setup()` method, which is invoked by the library when you call `load_extension()`. You can use this function to attach the cog to your bot.

Loading the extension in your bot's file:

```py
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    ...
    async def setup_hook(self):
        # This is typically done by looping over a directory of Cog files
        # instead of 1 by 1, but this is just an example
        await self.load_extension("path.to.your.extension")
```

Attaching the Cog in your extension's file:

```py
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this made my bot fully work and I'm grateful! I just want to say thank you and have a great day!